# I couldn't use apt to update, upgrade and install on raspberry wheezy

Tags: startx

I'm using raspberry pi and wheezy software. When I update I'm getting an error message like:

```
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease [12.5 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy InRelease [7,737 B]
Get:3 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Sources [6,234 kB]  
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main armhf Packages [6,413 B]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB                                     
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en                                        
Get:5 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Sources [52.7 kB]                                   
Get:6 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Sources [97.1 kB]                                  
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Sources                                              
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Sources                                                   
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages                                           
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages                                        
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages                                       
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi armhf Packages                                            
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en_GB                                     
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en                                        
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB                                        
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en                                           
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_GB                                    
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en                                       
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en_GB                                         
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en                                            
  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:
Fetched 6,313 kB in 44s (143 kB/s)                                                                   
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/non-free/source/Sources  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/rpi/source/Sources  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/rpi/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/rpi/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.raspbian.org:http:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But downloading it manually from my computer (different one) and pasting it into the SD card and running it again also didn't work. I wasn't able to download plugins to use Webvisu or Iceweasel web browser. Can anybody help me with this issue?

I have even tried to use Raspbian Jessie Lite and Jessie, but after username and password I wasn't able to continue(if I tried startx as normal after the username and password it also did not work.)

Answer (score 0):

You might try to remove the contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/`. This contains cached copies of your lists, so that only changes need to be downloaded, and is known to sometimes cause issues.

Comment: can you explain how to remove.  bec after i write in sd card then insert in -raspberry pi and starting the pi and just enter sudo apt-get update in the first command in terminal this msg is coming.

Comment: s any body know y my startx s not working in jessie and jessi lite